# Site Column not appear in meta data Crawl Properties - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, managed-property, content-search-web-part, sharepoint-search

I've created a choice column as site column(Hidepoemdata) and associated with multiple document libraries.

I've make Index column for the site column to each document libraries and waited for sometime to SharePoint Online get done crawling using crawl service.

However, the site column is not appearing as Managed Property into Search Schema.

How can I get rid of this issue?

Comment: Is this a Modern Team site? If so, I have a ticket with MSFT on this one. They're investigating the issue. I can update this thread tomorrow once I hear back from their testing.

Comment: Try [Re-indexing](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9129cf05-f787-4212-81e3-72d753f7f15a/site-columns-are-not-showing-under-quotmanaged-propertiesquot-of-quotsearch-schemaquot) and full crawling again. Also make sure your site column fulfills all the criteria given [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/28448976-7b2a-4720-a1c8-f2af1e01596f/custom-columns-not-appearing-in-crawled-properties).

Comment: This is classic team site and I already tried with Reindex document library last week and check multiple times but no luck to be found.

Comment: Have you added at least one document that has the column populated with a value prior to performing a reindex?

Comment: @Trevor Seward - Yeah, I added column to library and set properties value on multiple documents, Reindex the same library. I performed all steps on last week and again one more time attempted on yesterday but no worked for me :(

Comment: If you search using the values of the column, do the matched results return?